# Placing a DIV in my header

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put a linkable image into my header RIGHT underneath the phone number but its not working.  My question is where do I place the div and how do I style it?

The code for me current header is:

```
<div class="header-right">
    <div class="social">
        <!--social media icons-->
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a class="contact" href="http://" title="Contact Us"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="google" href="http:/" target="_blank" title="Share on Google+"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="facebook" href="http:/" target="_blank" title="Share on Facebook"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="twitter" href="http:/" target="_blank" title="Share on Twitter"></a>
            </li>                                                                                    
        </ul>                
    </div> 
    <div class="telephone">           
        <p class="tel">Speak with<br/> 
            <a href="tel:08000000000"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></a><br />
            <small>Available 08:30 - 17:00, Mon-Fri</small>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. This is impossible to answer with any confidence without more of your code - in particular, the CSS for the already existing elements, and full HTML from the top of the page till that point, since "right underneath" can be affected by pretty much anything. Also, "not working" is useless as a report, since we have no information as to how exactly it's not working (not displaying? displaying but above? displaying in too much pink?) You might also want to recreate your problem in jsfiddle, if you want us to look at it.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="header-right">
    <div class="social">
        <!--social media icons-->
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a class="contact" href="http://" title="Contact Us"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="google" href="http:/" target="_blank" title="Share on Google+"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="facebook" href="http:/" target="_blank" title="Share on Facebook"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="twitter" href="http:/" target="_blank" title="Share on Twitter"></a>
            </li>                                                                                    
        </ul>                
    </div> 
    <div class="telephone">           
        <p class="tel">Speak with<br/> 
            <a href="tel:08000000000">info</a><br />
            <div>an image</div>
            <small>Available 08:30 - 17:00, Mon-Fri</small>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```